# Magento: execute a php file via shell from a backend module

Tags: magento

I have created a custom module with a backend menu item.
How can I let my custom menu item to execute a php file via shell (with php -f filename) ?

I'm using Magento version 1.6.2

Thanks for help.

Comment: sorry for offtop but why do you need this in extension? Btw, functions `exec()`, `system()`, `passtru()` and others from http://php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php can be disabled by security reasons in server configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php functions like `exec()`, `system()` or `passtru()` in your controller action, which is linked on the menu item.